# iOS: How to know zoom level of GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, zooming, gmsmapview

Hello I want to get current zoom level of `Google Map view`, like in a condition to check.
For example,

```
if(mapView.zoom==18.0)
{
 //code goes here..
}
```

How to get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395
#define MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS 20

@interface MKMapView (ZoomLevel)
- (double)getZoomLevel;
@end

@implementation MKMapView (ZoomLevel)

- (double)getZoomLevel
{
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = self.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = self.bounds.size.width;
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS - log2( zoomScale );
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
//  zoomer = round(zoomer);
    return zoomer;
}

@end
```

Also can use MKCoordinateSpan check [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html) for more information.

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;
} MKCoordinateSpan;
```

Comment: There is also third party class available https://github.com/warmshowers/warmshowers-iphone-app/blob/master/Classes/MKMapView%2BZoomLevel.m

Comment: Code contains all about MKMapView ! Does this work for Google Map View also ? I wonder.

Comment: For google map you can use GMSCameraPosition to get zoom level. Have a look on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_position

Comment: CGFloat currentZoom = self.MapView.camera.zoom;

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it works for you so other can also get idea from this post.

Answer (score 35):

It's pretty easy. GMSMapView has a camera ([GMSCameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_position)) property that has a zoom property.

```
CGFloat zoom = mapView.camera.zoom;
```

Note that zoom property is readonly.